# 'You know nothing OF THAT OF WHICH we speak'

Tags: prepositions, that

'You know nothing of that of which we speak'.

I know the sentence is formal, verbose and arguably clumsy; however, I'd like to know whether 
'*of that of which*' is grammatically correct.

Thanks.

Comment: It's ok, but I would change the first *of* to *about* to avoid repetition.

Comment: It is somewhat formal - literary or from some religious text perhaps? Grammatically, "that" means "the thing/matter", and "of which we speak" is a relative clause modifying it.

Answer (score 8):

It is correct. The first "of" means "about", or "regarding". "That of which we speak" is a noun phrase. It could be replaced by any noun. Imagine you replaced "that of which we speak" with the word "mountains" or "philosophy". It still works, so it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, technically, it's correct: "that of which we speak" is a noun phrase, the object of the preposition "of"; "of which we speak" is a common locution to avoid the faux faux-pas of ending a sentence with a preposition.